# combine columns, pickup_date with pickup_time = unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

1. combine two columns, pickup_date with pickup_time
2. pickup_date = 2015-02-10
3. pickup_24 = 08:46:15
4. code = df[pickup_start] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_date2'] + ' ' + df['pickup_24'])
5. error = unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'
6. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
import pandas as pd

pickup_date2 = '2015-02-10' 
pickup_24 = '08:46:15'
```

Below I am putting your times and dates in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pickup_date2":pickup_date2,"pickup_24":pickup_24}, index=[0])
```

Add the columns to create a new column as so,

```
df['date_time']=df['pickup_date2']+':'+df['pickup_24']
```

And then we can convert this column to pandas datetime,

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'],format='%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
```

Above I specified the formatting.

Old code:

With no data or code its hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

But, you should convert these columns to datetime.

```
df[pickup_date2] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_date2'])
df[pickup_24] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'])
```

then,

```
df[pickup_start] = df[pickup_date2] + df[pickup_24]
```

If your format for each of these columns are easily detectable by pandas then it should work.  If not, read [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: (1,) CODE:  df[pickup_24] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24']) (2.) ERROR: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'

Comment: df[picku_24] is a military time (24 hours)

Comment: added an update above.  It runs on my computer well.